# Как заполнить одинаковые подряд строки одним значением

Tags: sql, hive, impala

У меня есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (`Time` TIMESTAMP, Text string, Nm int);

insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:11:43', 'a', 1);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:11:43', 'a', 2);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:11:43', 'b', 3);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:13:12', 'a', 4);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:13:13', 'a', 5);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:13:13', 'a', 6);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:13:13', 'c', 7);
insert into table table_name values ('2021-10-10 12:13:17', 'c', 8);


Time      Text       Nm
2021-10-10 12:11:43       a       1
2021-10-10 12:11:43       a       2
2021-10-10 12:11:43       b       3
2021-10-10 12:13:12       a       4
2021-10-10 12:13:13       a       5
2021-10-10 12:13:13       a       6
2021-10-10 12:13:13       c       7
2021-10-10 12:13:17       c       8
```

Я хочу получить таблицу:

```
Time      Text       Nm       Value
2021-10-10 12:11:43       a       1             1
2021-10-10 12:11:43       a       2             1
2021-10-10 12:11:43       b       3             2
2021-10-10 12:13:12       a       4             3
2021-10-10 12:13:13       a       5             3
2021-10-10 12:13:13       a       6             3
2021-10-10 12:13:13       c       7             4
2021-10-10 12:13:17       c       8             4
```

Возможно уже есть готовая функция, позволяющая сделать это быстро?
Использую Hive или Impala.

Comment: СУБД и точную версию укажите... *Возможно уже есть готовая функция* - да кому оно бы надо?

Comment: dense_rank(), если сможете определить порядок.

Comment: @Akina использую Hive или Impala

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko совпадающие `Text` не смущают? тут не Rank(), а скорее `SUM(text <> LAG(text))` получается.

Comment: *использую Hive или Impala* Во-первых - добавьте соотв. тег (да и в тексте вопроса указать невредно). Во-вторых, заданный Сергеем вопрос об определении порядка - ключевой для решения задачи, особенно с учётом того, что в таблице понятия относительного порядка записей не существует. PS. Вообще - читать про "gaps and islands".

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko если правильно понимаю, порядок определить не получиться. В рамках подряд повторяющихся значений ```Text``` может быть как одинаковое время записи, так и разное.

Comment: То есть время записи всё-таки есть... вот что, адекватная модель у Вас не получается - покажите реальные CREATE TABLE и пример данных в виде INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina добавил информацию

Comment: Есть записи, для которых порядок неразличим. Задача - нерешаемая. Вводите дополнительные сведения в таблицу. Например, автоинкремент-ключ. Или пишите время с миллисекундами.

Comment: @Akina нашёл в данных атрибут, который позволяет установить порядок. Может сейчас есть мысли, как решить мою задачу?

Comment: @Akina спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN `Text` = LAG(`Text`) OVER (ORDER BY Nm)
                   THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
                   END value_changed
    FROM table_name
)
SELECT *, SUM(value_changed) OVER (ORDER BY Nm) 
FROM cte;
```